# How to Sum Rows in SQLite in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to add the items together, but they come out separately. There are 3 item weights from weapons that are equiped. Here is the code:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('character.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("SELECT * FROM equipment WHERE character_id = :character_id AND equip = :equip",
    {
        'character_id': self.controller.currentid.get(),
        'equip': 1

    })
    for row in c.fetchall():
        wconn = sqlite3.connect('equipment.db')
        w = wconn.cursor()
        w.execute("SELECT * FROM weapons WHERE weapon_id = :weapon_id",
        {
            'weapon_id': str(row[1])

        })
        for row1 in w.fetchall():
            test = str(row1[4])
            print(test)
        wconn.commit()
        wconn.close()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

My output is:
1.0
0.5
10.0

I want this to read 11.5 instead of the separate numbers.

Comment: ```for row1 in w.fetchall():
            test = str(row1[4])``` what is in row1[4]

Comment: This is returning all the weapon weight values from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SUM` function in your query:

```
SELECT SUM(column_to_sum) FROM weapons WHERE weapon_id = :weapon_id
```

You'll need to replace `column_to_sum` with the actual column name.

Comment: I have tried this, but it shows the number from each row and does not sum them together to make one number. I'm also using real numbers, or floats if that makes a difference.